# Update PHP class from mssql_ to sqlsrv_

Tags: php, sql-server

We've just updated PHP on our server, for the most part everything is fine, but the mssql_ functions aren't supported any more unfortunately. I've tried to update our previous class:

```
$connection['server'] = 'server, port';
$connection['user'] = 'user';
$connection['pass'] = 'pass';
$connection['db'] = 'db';

class mssqlClass {
    function connect($dbhost = NULL){
        global $connection;
        if(! ISSET ($dbconnect)){
            $dbconnect = mssql_Connect($connection['server'], $connection['user'], $connection['pass'], true);
        }
        if(! $dbconnect){
            return 'Failed to Connect to Host';
        }else{
            $select = mssql_select_db($connection['db'], $dbconnect);
            if(! $select){
                return 'Failed to select Database';
            }else{
                return $dbconnect;
            }
        }
    }

    function getData ($query){
        $this->data_array = array();
        $result = mssql_query($query);
        while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $this->data_array[] = $row;                                                    
        }
        $m = $this->data_array;                     
        return $m;
    }    
    function query($query){           
        $result = mssql_query($query) or die("Query didn't work");
    }
}
```

To be compliant with sqlsrv_, and whilst I can connect to the database without any issues, it won't return any data!:

```
class mssqlClass {
    function connect($database = 'Db') {
        $mssql_server = 'server';
        $mssql_data = array("UID" => 'uid',
                        "PWD" => 'pwd',
                        "Database" => $database);
        if(! ISSET ($dbconnect)){
            $dbconnect = sqlsrv_connect($mssql_server, $mssql_data);
        }
        if(! $dbconnect){
            return 'Failed to connect to host';
        }
    }

    function getData ($query) {
        $result = sqlsrv_query($db->connect, $query);
        while ($row =  sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {

                    $this->data_array[] = $row;                                                    
        }
        $m = $this->data_array;                     
        return $m;
    } 
    function query($query) {           
        $result = sqlsrv_query($query) or die("Query didn't work.");
    }
}
```

ps. Example usage is as follows:

```
$db = new mssqlClass();
$conn = $db->connect('DATABASE');

$query = "SELECT * FROM Table";
$result= $db->getData($query);
```

So sorry for the horrible amount of code - I can edit it down to just the getData function if that's easier? Thank you!!

Comment: What is `$db` meant to be in `getData()`?

Comment: You know that's a good question! I wrote this code very late last night and have no idea where that came from, possibly the help docs that came with the extension package, d'oh! Ty

Comment: I'd suggest to turn on error reporting on development box - `error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT); ini_set('display_errors', true);`. It will help to find problems like undefined variables, non-existent array indexes etc ;)

Comment: This is a very good shout, thank you! Sorry to be stupid, but any idea on how to reference the connection class (as above with $db) *without* passing it in when I call the function? Would require me to change a crazy amount of code, was wrote ages ago by someone else and isn't easy to update :/ Ty!

Comment: d'oh, also - error reporting on, with no errors to report! still no data though. Almost certain it's the reference to the $db connection that you mentioned

Comment: I would store connection as object's parameter in `connect()`, i.e., instead of assigning it to method's local variable with `$dbconnect = sqlsrv_connect(...)`, assign it to object's variable with `$this->connection = sqlsrv_connect(...)`. Then, in other methods, you will be able to access it via `$this->connection` (instead of `$db->connection`). You should also define it somewhere before other methods, like `class mssqlClass { protected $connection; public function connect(...) {...} }`.

Comment: Oh my god! Thank you so so SO much, can't explain how much of a headache you have saved me, please copy and paste as a solution so I can give you a tick:)

Comment: I went through this a few months back, quick tip, probably does not apply to you but I will mention it anyhow: Zend_DB and its related classes just about manage to make playing with MSSQL fun.

Comment: I prefer PDO for working with databases. Haven't used it with MSSQL though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've made some changes in your class:

```
<?php

class mssqlClass {

    protected $connection = null;

    public function connect($database = 'Db') {
        // we don't need to connect twice
        if ( $this->connection ) {
            return;
        }
        // data for making connection            
        $mssql_server = 'gc-hr01';
        $mssql_data = array("UID" => 'uid',
                        "PWD" => 'pwd',
                        "Database" => $database);
        // try to connect                    
        $this->connection = sqlsrv_connect($mssql_server, $mssql_data);
        if(! $dbconnect){
            return 'Failed to connect to host';
        }
    }

    public function getData ($query) {
        // reset results; is this really needed as object's variable? Can't it be just local function's variable??
        $this->data_array = array();
        $result = $this->query($this->connection, $query);
        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
            $this->data_array[] = $row;                                                    
        }
        return $this->data_array;                     
    }

    public function query($query) {           
        $result = sqlsrv_query($query) or die("Query didn't work..");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code looks fine. The only thing which could be your problem is that sqlsrv_fetch_array needs maybe a second parameter e.g.:

```
sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)
```

Because the default is that it returns two arrays with different formats. And if you may acess attributes by name it will return nothing but not fail.

Something like this. Because you actually call the sqlsrv_query method with the return value of the following method. And in the original version you missed to return the connection resource.

```
function connect($database = 'Db') {

    $mssql_server = 'gc-hr01';
    $mssql_data = array("UID" => 'uid',
                    "PWD" => 'pwd',
                    "Database" => $database);
    $dbconnect = sqlsrv_connect($mssql_server, $mssql_data);

    if(! $dbconnect){
        return 'Failed to connect to host';
    }
    return $dbconnect;
}
```

in advance

```
function getData ($query) {
    $result = sqlsrv_query($db->connect(), $query);
    while ($row =  sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                $this->data_array[] = $row;                                                    
    }
    $m = $this->data_array;                     
    return $m;
} 
function query($query) {           
    $result = sqlsrv_query($query) or die("Query didn't work.");
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! I've just updated the line to '($row =  sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))' and still no data unfortunately, but it's good progress :) thank you

Comment: You need to return the connection resource ;) you forgot this while porting the code.

Comment: D'oh, you were right, thank you so much! Only just noticed this edit too, damn sorry :) Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

I found this page while trying to find a quick short-cut to someone else's wrapper class for sqlsrv commands. Since this wasn't really complete, I have compiled my own quickly. Please don't think this is production code, you should test and test again, but it might help someone out of a jam quickly.

```
class db {

    protected $connection = null;
    private $debug = true;
    private $stmt = null;
    private $insertid = null;
    private $affectedrows = null;

    public function db($host = '.',$database,$username,$password) {
        // we don't need to connect twice
        if ( $this->connection ) {
            return;
        }

        sqlsrv_configure('WarningsReturnAsErrors', 0);

        // data for making connection            
        $sqlsvr_details =   array(  'UID'   => $username,
                                    'PWD'           => $password,
                                    'Database'      => $database,
                                    'CharacterSet'  => 'UTF-8'
                                );

        // try to connect                    
        $this->connection = sqlsrv_connect($host, $sqlsvr_details);

        if($this->connection == false){
            $this->debug('Failed to connect to host: '.$this->errors(),true);
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function query($query) {           
        return new resultset($query,$this->connection,$this->debug);
    }

    private function debug ($message,$hard = false){
        if ($this->debug){
            if ($hard){
                die($message);
            }else{
                echo $message;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

public function delete($query){
    return $this->update($query);   
}

public function update($query){
    //Not happy with this
    $this->affectedrows = null;
    $this->insertid = null;

    $this->stmt = sqlsrv_query($this->connection, $query);

    if (!$this->stmt){
        $this->debug('SQL Query Failed: '.$query.' '.$this->errors(),true);
        return false;
    }else{
        $this->affectedrows = @sqlsrv_rows_affected($this->stmt);
        return $this;   
    }
}

public function insert($query){
    //Not happy with this
    $this->affectedrows = null;
    $this->insertid = null;

    $this->stmt = sqlsrv_query($this->connection, $query);

    if (!$this->stmt){
        $this->debug('SQL Query Failed: '.$query.' '.$this->errors(),true);
        return false;
    }else{
        //Get the last insert ID and store it on here
        $this->insertid = $this->query('select @@IDENTITY as insert_id')->asObject()->insert_id;
        return $this;   
    }
}

public function insert_id(){
    return $this->insertid;
}

public function affected_rows(){
    return $this->affectedrows; 
}

private function errors(){
    return print_r( sqlsrv_errors(SQLSRV_ERR_ERRORS), true);
}

}

class resultset implements Countable,Iterator {

    private $result = null;
    private $connection = null;
    private $debug = false;
    private $internal_pointer = 0;
    private $data = array();

    public function resultset($query,$link,$debug = false){
        $this->connection = $link;
        $this->debug = $debug;

        $this->result = sqlsrv_query($this->connection, $query, array(),  array('Scrollable' => SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC));

        if ($this->result == false){
            $this->debug('Query Failed: '.$query.' '.$this->errors(),true);
            return false;
        }else{
            return $this;
        }
    }

    public function asObject($step = true){
        $object = sqlsrv_fetch_object($this->result,NULL,NULL,SQLSRV_SCROLL_ABSOLUTE,$this->internal_pointer);
        if (! $object){
            return false;
        }else{
            if ($step) $this->internal_pointer++;
            return $object; 
        }

    }

    public function num_rows() {
        return sqlsrv_num_rows($this->result);
    }

    public function free(){
        $this->internal_pointer = 0;

        if (is_resource($this->result)){
            sqlsrv_free_stmt($this->result);
        }   
    }

    public function __destory(){
        $this->free();
    }

        //Countable Function

    public function count(){
        return $this->num_rows();   
    }

    //Iteration Functions

    public function rewind(){
        $this->internal_pointer = 0;    
    }

    public function current(){
        return $this->asObject(false);
    }

    public function key(){
        return $this->internal_pointer;
    }

    public function next(){
        $this->internal_pointer++;
    }

    public function valid(){
        return $this->internal_pointer <= $this->num_rows();    
    }

    //============================================

    private function debug ($message,$hard = false){
        if ($this->debug){
            if ($hard){
                die($message);
            }else{
                echo $message;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private function errors(){
        return print_r( sqlsrv_errors(SQLSRV_ERR_ERRORS), true);
    }
}
```